# Spring beans creation with different annotations

Tags: java, spring, annotations, initialization, javabeans

I have a bean configuration like this:

```
@Bean(NAME)  
@ConfigurationProperties(PROPS)  
public SomeBean getSomeBean(@Qualifier(QUALIFIER) X x) {  
    return new SomeBean(x);  
}
```

And there are a lot of classes with the same configuration, but different constants (NAME, PROPS, QUALIFIER). I thought about passing them from constructor (initializing constant fields) or overridden methods, but it wouldn't work because annotations require only constants.

Is there any way to create something like a base class and share this bean initialization, passing only specific constants?

Answer (score 0):

In order to promote reusability and minimize development effort, Spring supports bean definition inheritance.

The below example code explains the process. In the java configuration file write

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    public Employee employee() {
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        initCompany(employee);
        employee.setLocation("XYZ");
        return employee;
    }
    private void initCompany(Company company) {
        company.setName("abc");
        company.setAge(30);
    }
}
```

In the main class to run write

```
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
public class SpringDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(AppConfig.class);
        ctx.refresh();
        Employee employee = ctx.getBean(Employee.class);
        System.out.println(employee.getName());
        System.out.println(employee.getLocation());
        System.out.println(employee.getAge());
            ctx.registerShutdownHook();
    }
} 

Output
```

```
  abc 
  XYZ
  30
```